# How to get docker container id when starting container

Tags: docker

When writing a bash script that starts a docker container, it is useful to refer to the started docker container. How do you get the specific container id of a docker container when you start it?

P.S. I know that I can use `--name` to name the container, which I can use to filter the list of containers using `docker ps -aqf "name=containername"`, but this will fail if I ever start the script twice. And then there's the possibility of name conflicts. Besides, what's the point of container IDs if you can't use them?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you start a detached container, it returns the container ID. e.g.:

```sh
$ docker run -d ubuntu:18.04
71329cf6a02d89cf5f211072dd37716fe212787315ce4503eaee722da6ddf18f
```

In bash, you can define a new variable from the output like this:

```sh
CID=$(docker run -d ubuntu:18.04)
```

Then, later you can use this variable to refer to your container like this:

```sh
docker stop $CID
docker rm $CID
```

Answer (score 5):

In the documentation for `docker run` under ["capture container id"](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/#capture-container-id---cidfile), they advise using the `--cidfile` flag for this purpose.

`--cidfile` takes a file name as an argument and will write the long ID of the container to that location. E.g.,

```
docker run --cidfile /tmp/hello-world.cid hello-world && cat /tmp/hello-world.cid
```

This is useful when you don't want to run the image in a detached state, but still want access to the ID.

Comment: For anyone who was looking: this is not available in [docker-compose](https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/940).